# Wigner $D$ Matrix and Angular Momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory

Sakurai says Wigner functions vanish for different $j$ value. Should it not also vanish for different $m$ value as the state is orthonormal and if that's true then what would be the entries of blocks in block diagonal matrix.

Sorry for image as it was not possible to put up matrix in any other way!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the first angular momentum eigenstate orthogonal to the second? Yes.

Is the first angular momentum eigenstate orthogonal to whatever you get by acting on the second with some $J_\pm$ generators? No.

Note that the equation at the top of page has $\delta_{m, m^\prime \pm 1}$ which is not the same as $\delta_{m, m^\prime}$. Since this equation is very explicit, it's enough to tell you what the off-diagonal D-matrix elements are within each block. After some tedious Taylor expansion that is.